# problem with mktime and timezone

Tags: php, timestamp, mktime

I would like to display the time stamp of 00:00:00 1 Nov 2010 with the code as below

> $day = mktime(0,0,0,11,1,2010);

However, it always display the wrong timestamp from what I intended.
For example,

> date('h m s d m y', $day);

will return '12 11 00 01 11 10'

It always behind 12hr and 11min. May I know what went wrong? How to rectify? Thanks..

Comment: The first m which should be minutes i guess is months, use i for minutes.
date('h m s d m y', $day);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong date format string. Check out the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the correct format string options.

For your example you probably want `date('H i s d m y',$day)`

Answer (score 0):

print(date('H i s d m y', mktime(0,0,0,11,1,2010))); is what you want I guess